# TCP socket connect times out in Xamarin app on Android, but not on Desktop

Tags: android, sockets, xamarin, tcp

I'm getting timeouts while trying to connect a TCP socket in a cross-platform C# app (Avalonia/Xamarin) - but the behavior is very peculiar:

- The server is a piece of hardware/industrial equipment. It acts as a WiFi AP, to which client devices connect & control it through a TCP socket.
- The existing client software is written in C#/WinForms. Let's call it DesktopController.
- I'm now writing a cross-platform version in Avalonia. Let's call it AvaloniaController.
- AvaloniaController shares the same (existing) network code as DesktopController, and can connect the socket when running on Windows. However, from Android, the socket connections always timeout `System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (110): Connection timed out`
- I also have "ServerSimulator", a C# Desktop application that mocks the behavior of the hardware for development purposes. I can connect to ServerSimulator from AvaloniaController, *both* on Windows and on Android. This shows that the socket code definitely does work on Android - otherwise, we wouldn't be able to connect to ServerSimulator.
- AvaloniaController also cannot connect when running in an Android emulator, on the same physical PC as where AvaloniaController on Windows. This shows that it isn't something specific to the physical Android device.

The code for connecting is as simple as:

```
public void Connect(string host, int port)
{
    IPAddress ipAddress;
    IPAddress.TryParse(host, out ipAddress);
    IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

    try
    {
        _tcpSocket = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // On Android, it pauses here for a bit & then times out/throws
        _tcpSocket.Connect(ipe);
    }
}
```

Why would this code be able to connect Windows->Hardware, Windows->ServerSimulator, Android->ServerSimulator...but timeout on Android->Hardware?

Comment: Please tell about the ip's the clients use.

Comment: When connecting to the physical hardware's wifi AP, it's always at a fixed IP - 192.168.42.1. When connecting to the simulator, you connect to whatever the LAN IP of that system is - i.e. 192.168.1.20 or whatever. Or if running the simulator on the same Windows machine & running the Windows software, you can connect via 127.0.0.1 obviously.

Comment: If your app runs on the emulator and the server runs on the same machine as the emulator runs your client app has to use ip 10.0.2.2.

Comment: As stated tho, the issue also exists when running on a physical phone. I only tried the emulator after finding that the physical phone failed. Also, I am able to connect to the ServerSimulator from the emulator, when both are on the same physical PC, by using that physical PC's LAN address. But the issue isn't with connecting to the server software - it's with connecting to the physical equipment, per the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The issue was that if the Android device has another Internet connection, then it fails to resolve the IP; if you put it on Airplane Mode & then connect to the WiFi network, it works. Since the phone had Internet through its SIM card, and the emulator did through the host PC's connection, they both failed.